# How to write to a xml in WPF XBAP Applications

Tags: wpf

I am new to WPF.I want to get data from the form and in button click event i want to write that data into a xml and store that xml to a local folder.But i am getting an error as

> "Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission,mscorlib,version=2.0.0.0,Cultur=neutral,Public
>   KeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed"

Can anyone Pls help what i need to do...I searched in many ways.